# Snowflake-how to get existing table sql script

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am coming from the world of MCFT-SQL and to get a script view of an existing table I used to do right click and get sql for that table and MSSQL would just put that in the script view.

With snowflake which I am just starting today, I want to be able to get the script of an existing table, just need help in finding a quick way of scripting the existing table preferably without using python. I dont even know if its even possible to get SQL script of an existing object in this case table or not.

Doing right click on stat_table2 does not give any options, need help with that please.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the get_ddl() function - here is the reference:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl.html

Comment: Thanks, when I do select get_ddl('table', 'ACCOUNTS_DIFFERENCE') it says Table 'ACCOUNTS_DIFFERENCE' does not exist. Do I need to give the name of the database and schema before the table name?

Comment: yes, I did, figured it out.. select get_ddl('table', 'Mydb.myschema.ACCOUNTS_DIFFERENCE')

Comment: Yes, more often than not, it is best to provide fully qualified database and schema specification for tables.  Does this function provide the information you needed?